# Changing Language of DateTime Error

Tags: c#, datetime

So I am trying to change the language of a DateTime in C# from English to French. It was working perfectly yesterday, made a few changes (that had nothing to do with the date at all) come back today and am running into this error:

An exception o type System.FormatException occured in msorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional Information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here is my code:

```
        string period;

        period = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["Period"]);
        string format = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy";

        string fDate = from.ToLongDateString();
        var fr = DateTime.ParseExact(fDate, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        var fromDate = fr.ToString("D", new CultureInfo(this.BGUser.UICultureInfoString));

        string tDate = to.ToLongDateString();
        var td = DateTime.ParseExact(tDate, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        var toDate = td.ToString("D", new CultureInfo(this.BGUser.UICultureInfoString));

        if (period == null)
            return "<b>" + this.Translate("Orders due ", 4386) + fromDate + " - " + toDate + "</b>";
        else if (period.Equals("archive"))
            return "<b>" + this.Translate("Orders due before ", 4387) + toDate + "</b>";
        else if (period.Equals("future"))
            return "<b>" + this.Translate("Orders due after ", 4388) + fromDate + "</b>";
```

It is specifically getting the error on the line

```
        var fr = DateTime.ParseExact(fDate, format, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The from and to are DateTime variables that are passed into the function and are correct. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I strongly feel you are doing unnecessary things since your `from` and `to` _already_ seems as `DateTime`. o.O

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for your response. Do you have any better methods of changing the language of a date? This is just the method I found through my research

Comment: A DateTime value in .NET *doesn't **have** a "language"*, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the language of a DateTime". A DateTime represents a specific point in time. It sounds like you want to *format* a DateTime in a particular culture, which is different. For that, remove all of your code and replace with `var fromDate = fDate.toString("D", new CultureInfo(this.BGUser.UICultureInfoString));`

Comment: If `from` is already a `DateTime`, why are you converting it to a string and then trying to parse it back? Can you verify which type `from` really is?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and MikeMcCaughan you guys are correct. Not too sure what I was thinking. My solution is posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I took your comments into account and did this which seems to work

```
        var fromDate = from.ToString("D", new CultureInfo(this.BGUser.UICultureInfoString));
        var toDate = to.ToString("D", new CultureInfo(this.BGUser.UICultureInfoString));
```